# Qual o significado e forma de uso de volume no Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Em um arquivo Dockerfile qual o significado da instrução:

```
VOLUME /arquivos
```

Imagino que isso crie um volume, mas como isso é usado e qual seu real significado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No dockerfile os volumes informam ao docker os pontos de montagem nos containers criados a partir da imagem que está construindo (com o dockerfile).

Isso permite ao docker alocar volumes dinamicamente, ou ainda informar para os consumidores da imagem quais são os pontos de montagem necessários para se manter estado dos containers criados com a tal imagem.

No DockerFile os volumes são definidos como:

`VOLUME /path/dir/1/
VOLUME /path/dir/2/`

Você pode ainda informar vários volumes (não precisa ser um só) em várias sentenças ou em formato de array: como abaixo.

`VOLUME ["/path/dir/1/", "/path/dir/2/"]`

No subcomandos *Docker **Run***/*Docker **Create*** o parâmetro curto -v ou a versão longa --volume são usados para mapear volumes. Entretanto não há obrigatoriedade/restrição alguma. Você pode mapear os volumes que foram determinados no dockerfile ou outros volumes, ou ainda ignorá-los. Não há validação alguma quanto a isso, portanto é preciso ter atenção e cuidado.

Answer (score 0):

Volume é quando você precisa compartilhar diretório ou pasta entre o filesystem do host e o filesystem do container.

VOLUME /opt/host /opt/container

No dockerfile sempre o primeiro parâmetro refere-se ao host e o segundo parâmetro refere-se ao mapeado para o container.

Por outro lado, se você omitir o segundo parâmetro como abaixo, então no docker run você poderá passá-lo ou pedir que o docker faça automaticamente.

EXPOSE 8080

Quando rodar o comando "docker run" e passar o comando abaixo então uma porta aleatória irá ser mapeada no host para o porta 8080 do container.

docker run -p 8080

Ou podemos usar:

docker run -p 80:8080

O comando acima quer dizer que a porta 80 do host irá acessar a porta 8080 do container.

Comment: Volume (no dockerfile) não possui 2 partes e não tem relação entre host e container.